# Extract strings based on a database in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, extract, stringr

From my data I want to extract the strings that are between the L and R string from my database.

My database includes 4 different L and R string combinations and I want to test all of them.

One way is to write a for loop, but is there any more elegant and clever way?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-  c("CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA",
          "CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA",
          "CCACGAAGCTCTCCTAGGGGGGGGCTATTTTGGACTGCGTTACCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGGAATCTAGTTCGA",
          "CCACGTAGCTCTCCTCCGTGCGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(seq=1)

database=data.frame(L=c("CTACG","CTAGG","CTCCG"), R=c("CAGTC","CAGTC","CAGTC"))


data %>% 
  mutate(extracts= str_extract(.$seq,
  str_c("(?<=",str_c(database[1,1], collapse = ""),").*(?=",str_c(database[1,2], collapse = ""),")")))
#>                                                                                 seq
#> 1 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#> 2 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#> 3 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTAGGGGGGGGCTATTTTGGACTGCGTTACCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGGAATCTAGTTCGA
#> 4 CCACGTAGCTCTCCTCCGTGCGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#>                    extracts
#> 1 TACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGG
#> 2 TACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGG
#> 3                      <NA>
#> 4                      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It looks brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create your unique patterns and then apply across them. Then you can just `cbind` your results with your original data frame.

```r
library(stringr)

patterns <- paste0(database$L, "(.*)", database$R)

names(patterns) <- paste0("pattern", 1:3)

cbind(
  data,
  lapply(
    patterns,
    \(x) str_match(data$seq, x)[,2]
  )
)
#>                                                                                 seq
#> 1 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#> 2 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#> 3 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTAGGGGGGGGCTATTTTGGACTGCGTTACCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGGAATCTAGTTCGA
#> 4 CCACGTAGCTCTCCTCCGTGCGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCAGCGCCAACCAGATAAGTGAAATCTAGTTCCA
#>                    pattern1                  pattern2                  pattern3
#> 1 TACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGG                      <NA>                      <NA>
#> 2 TACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGG                      <NA>                      <NA>
#> 3                      <NA> GGGGGGCTATTTTGGACTGCGTTAC                      <NA>
#> 4                      <NA>                      <NA> TGCGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGG
```

This only captures the first match. If you need to capture additional matches, can get a bit more complex. I think easiest would be to generate all unique combinations of the patterns you want to check and sequences, then create a list column in `mutate()`. In this case we can go with your original lookaheads/behinds and use `str_extract_all()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

patterns <- paste0("(?<=", database$L, ")(.*)(?=", database$R, ")")
names(patterns) <- paste0("pattern", 1:3)

expand_grid(seq = data$seq,
            pattern = patterns) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(match = str_extract_all(seq, pattern)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "pattern",
    values_from = "match"
  ) %>%
  rename_with(~names(patterns),
              .cols = -seq)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   seq                                                 pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
#>   <chr>                                               <list>   <list>   <list>  
#> 1 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTACGTACGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCA… <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 2 CCACGAAGCTCTCCTAGGGGGGGGCTATTTTGGACTGCGTTACCAGTCCA… <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 3 CCACGTAGCTCTCCTCCGTGCGGTTATATTGACAGACCGAGGGCAGTCCA… <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
```